# org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONArray is deprecated in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem

In AEM 6.3,The JSONArray API is deprecated ,so what is the alternative in place of JSONArray API?

Comment: Can you provide a link to this deprecated API?

Comment: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/develop/ref/javadoc/deprecated-list.html

Comment: I answered this question in one of my blog:http://sgaem.blogspot.in/2017/08/alternatives-of-deprecated-json-api-in.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way forward is to change your Json API from org.apache.sling.commons.json to com.google.gson. Since it is already being used in AEM elsewhere.

[image: GSON Usage in AEM]

Comment: the org.json package is also available in AEM already. As the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55649821/3245114) explains this would be an easier package to transition to.

Answer (score 7):

Due to license issues these classes were removed with Sling 9. It simply was the json.org library.  Sling itself used it for a few things only, so Sling was refactored to get along without it.

I afraid, there is no replacement. You have to choose a different JSON library, include it into your project and port your code. As the JSON lib is pretty straight forward, it should be doable.

*Here some links with the mailing lists:*

https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/ee51bace078681765d5dcfeda1939628ccefb9b4261b1d7f6a56d420@%3Cdev.sling.apache.org%3E

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/www-legal-discuss/201611.mbox/browser

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-6536

Here is the license in question. It contains the ambiguous sentence "*The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil.*"

https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: Nice Explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way forward which avoids (most) code changes is to replace the Sling Commons JSON library with Org.Json *if you can live with the license change that caused it be deprecated in the first place*.

**Add to the pom.xml dependencies:**

You can add the org.json dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.json</groupId>
 <artifactId>json</artifactId>
 <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Or depending on version of AEM 
     use the granite bundled version instead -->

<dependency>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211_1</version>
    <groupId>com.adobe.granite.bundles</groupId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

OR use [Open-JSON](https://github.com/tdunning/open-json), a clean-room reimplementation by the Android team which has a standard Apache 2.0 license without the 'evil' clause:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tdunning</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update Import statements**

The Apache Sling Commons JSON is mostly a repackaged org.json parser, and appears to be compatible aside from package path differences. To change to the org.json or Open-Json parser, alter these imports:

```
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONArray;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.io.JSONWriter;
```

to

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONWriter;
```

For many this will be an acceptable and clean solution that doesn't require reworking all the code to use GSON or Jackson (both available in AEM).

Caveat: I've only tested this compiles... You might need to embed the parser in your bundle. Neither of these parsers claim to be OSGi aware.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any json API depending upon your requirement. I will suggest using Gson as its quite easy to use as one can map a json object directly to a pojo class and then use the object of the pojo class. It removes a lot of boilerplate code for reading the json objects one by one.